# Can't Find Option to Create Feature Layer

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-layer

I have created an ArcGIS online account but I can't find option to create feature layer.

I tried to create developers account, but yet didn't find a way to create feature layer service.

I have added map from CSV file, but don't find publish button so that it can be hosted using feature layer.

How do I host my service as feature layer?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What kind of ArcGIS Online account have you created?  Is it a paid subscription or a free account?  Free accounts are quite limited, and it is not possible to create feature layers directly.  I believe you'd need to publish the data from ArcMap and then access it from ArcGIS Online.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/review) to learn about our focussed Q&A format. You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a developers account you can create a feature service when you add the CSV as an item under My Content and you will see a checkbox to publish as a service. You can also create an empty feature service under your developer account defining the fields through the site. When you add the csv into the map that can either be a csv by reference where its accessing a hosted csv or it could embed the csv into the map if you are adding the file directly which will create essentially a feature collection much like map notes.